# Correlations in R

Tags: r

c.  What is the correlation coefficient between “beds” and “baths”  for the houses with total rooms not exceeding (i.e., less than or equal) 6 rooms (total rooms = “beds” + “baths”)

Data:

```
myData$beds + myData$baths
  [1]  5  5  6  5  5  5  5  7  6  5  5  5  6  6  5  6  5  6  5  6  6  5  7  5  5  8  5  5  7  5  7  7  6  7  8  6  7
 [38]  7  7  6  5  7  6  7  6  7  5  7  6  5  5  7  5  5  6  7  7  5  5  7  5  7  8  8  5  6  6  5  5  6  6  8  6  7
 [75]  7  6  6  6  7  6  6  7  7  6  6  6  8  7  6  8  6  9 10  7  7  7  6  6  6  7  8  7  6  7  7  7  7  7
```

How do I write code that does the `cor(myData$beds, myData$baths)`, with the condition that the sum of both is less than 6?

Comment: You should try either `subset()` in base R or `filter()` from the `dplyr` package to remove the unwanted observations and then you calculate the correlation coefficient on the result.

Comment: First create a subset of the data frame using the `subset()` function (`?subset` for the manual page). Provide reproducible data using `dput(head(myData, 20)` for a specific answer.

Comment: Greetings! Please share a reproducible dataset as shown here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg